# Check No. of cases created by User in a quarter in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 4 quarters in an year. If current month is 8th, so quarter is 1st-July-17 to 30th-Sept. Similarly if current month is 2nd, so quarter is 
1-Jan-16 to 31st-Mar-31.

How I need to query from the 1st-July-17 to today's date to check how many cases has been created by that user. How we can checked that ?

Comment: This is probably only part of what you are looking for but I hope it helps.  A SOQL query to retun all cases created between july 1st and today owned by a specific username.  Naturally it'll need to be tweaked if you want to it into a trigger somehow.     select id, casenumber, createddate, createdby.name from case where createddate >= 2017-07-01T00:00:00Z and createddate <= TODAY and createdby.name = 'username'.  Have you tried anything, it may help us  if you provide what you have got so far if it is to be used in a trigger..

Comment: Can somebody tell me the reason for downvote ? Else you can put quality questions so that beginner can learn from it or create blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use date literals:

```
WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_QUARTER
```

There is a corresponding literal for fiscal quarters if you are using custom fiscal quarters.

Comment: ... you know the CreatedDate field is strictly in the past right? Anyway there is also a date literal for `TODAY`. If you want to use merge variables you must precede them with bind syntax (`:variable`), but date literals are simpler. This stuff is covered really thoroughly in the developer guide.

Comment: I want to restrict user if he is submitting 20th Case in a quarter, thats it, Do I need to execute query between start date and end date ? When quarter starts ??

Comment: At any time in the quarter, the filter I list in my answer should completely suffice for your date filtering needs.

Comment: Calendar quarters... it's every three months starting in January, yeah.